# How to un-add a file after commiting?

Tags: git

I accidentally added some changes to a commit. I would like to remove those changes from the commit, but keep them in my working tree. Just to be clear, I did something like this:

```
git add xyz
git add unwanted # please make it as if I never typed this line
git commit -m 'nice xyz changes'
```

Is there an easy way to amend this commit such that the unwanted `git add` never happened before committing?

I guess I could take a diff, reset the file to how it was in the previous commit, amend the faulty commit and apply the diff. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Worth noting: the file `unwanted` was in the older commits, and you had modified it in your work-tree but wanted the newer commit to use the older version of the file, not the new updated version. (Otherwise the one answer provided below, at the time I write this comment, won't quite work!)

Comment: @torek Yes, exactly. I am bad at explaining things. But the checkout mentioned below does not quite satisfy my needs as it also overrides my working tree, not only my index with the older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that `git reset` is made exactly for my needs. It touches only the index and resets it to a specific commit (or more generally to some "tree-ish"). The working tree stays intact. This solves my problem:

```
git reset HEAD^ -- unwanted
git commit --amend
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- unwanted
git commit --amend
```

Comment: Hm, this does not seem to preserve my working tree.